# TeXnicCenter RegEx Syntax

Tags: editors

I'd like to use regular expressions to replace text in TeXnicCenter.
I think the capturing is done with [].
But I can't find out how to use the captured text in the replacing text.

E.g. I want to replace "24h" with "24 h".
It seems like I can capture the "4" using the search term "[\d]h".
I tried "\1 h", "$1 h", ... as replacing text, but nothing works.

Does anyone now the RegEx syntax to be used in TeXnicCenter?

[image]

Comment: What proof have you that texniccenter can do regex? I don't have it but nothing on the website or in the documentation says something about it.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer: Will the added picture be proof enough for you? ;-)

Comment: A secret. Well I install the program and tried. The capture seems to be `\(...\)`  and the replacement `\1`. But imho the implementation is very buggy. Sometimes I got a `\1` instead of the capture, and it didn't jump correctly to the next occurrences.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer: Thanks for your hints. As you pointed out, TeXnicCenter RegEx seems to be not very usable. In the future, I'll copy my texts to another editor when I need RegEx.